# Redesigning contact form

Tags: usability, website-design, contact-us, webforms

Contact form can have many fields but the minimum required fields are name, email and text field (message box). Name and email are usually located above message box. To simplify and make smaller in size my contact form I **removed name field**  and **moved email field** under the message box. I think if person wants he/she can write a name in a message box like "Hello,. my name is..."

My main reasons for doing this were: it looks better, contact from takes less space and it has less cognitive load as there are less fields to be filled.

Am I right, **did it reduce cognitive load?**

Here is an example of a complex design from [ivomynttinen.com](http://ivomynttinen.com/contact) where it's kind of a template that client has to fill. But client can describe all that in a message box in a way that is convenient to him. Options in drop downs menu make it restrictive and clients might not have all the answers yet so I decided to go with contact from as simple as it can be.

[image: ivomynttinen.com contact form]

As you see on the picture below, my contact form is really simple.

[image: my contact from]

**Did my contact form reduced cognitive load and is more user friendly as it appears like it's less to type?**

Comment: What if user doesn't have budget/timeline yet? Also reads a bit strange: My name is... How can I help... seems to be confusing

Comment: @Runnick, my contact form is the simple one. That first one with many fields is just to make a point that you really need a contact form if you can benefit from additional user input (like time and budget etc). In my case where there is only text box and email I'm hesitating about keeping it.

Comment: yes, so in this case your form is definitely easier, because other one wasn't carefully thought from the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your contact form certainly looks simpler! I suggest you keep the **Let's work together** title as is because it's better than **Let's make a great project**, and in message box you and ask for a specific message with a placeholder like: **Your professional introduction**

[image]

---

Here are some standard patterns of contact forms to refer:
http://ui-patterns.com/users/1/collections/contact_form/screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Conversation forms are trending a lot these days. The reason that this happens is because with this way you encourage the user to interact with the form by engaging them in a friendly dialogue instead of interrogating them.

I cannot be sure whether the user's cognitive load is reduced, but I can say that it appears to

- friendlier, because it is more like a conversation that you have with the UI
- simpler, because it looks smaller

The only drawback that the first form might have is the fact that it is not as conventional as the second form. Users are more used to a form like the second, but that doesn't mean that it is better. It would be very interesting to run a test to see if the first form increases the number of people contacted you.

Personally, I would advise you to keep the second, especially when it is your portfolio that we are talking about.

Why does it seem smaller in length?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUL3cn.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Not sure about the "simpler, because it looks smaller" since simulating conversations takes more words, so longer for a user to understand that "Hi, my name is (your name) and I'm with (company name) is the same as:

"Your name" + "Company name" as 2 separate fields

Comment: "Conversation forms are trending" - trending on which websites? Because browsing through many portfolio websites about 60% of them didn't have contact form, only email address.

Comment: @Peter There are some examples and more companies tend to use them more. I haven't done research on portfolios, but I think your claim is valid. In portfolios, people don't use so much the contact forms - actually me neither in my portfolio.

Comment: @JoaoCarvalho Exactly! It is not smaller, it looks smaller in terms of page length. Users are running away from long forms. They have the same fields, but in my eye at least they seem smaller.

Comment: @DimitraMiha but you still have the 2 fields but now on one line only and having more words, does it really makes the page length smaller? Not getting this point here, sorry

Comment: @JoaoCarvalho I edited my answer to demonstrate what I mean. Do I make sense now? Did you have something else in mind? I would be glad to receive your opinion.

Comment: @DimitraMiha ok got your point now and I agree that seems smaller. Now how could this be displayed on xs-sized screens since this possibility requires more width?

Comment: @JoaoCarvalho very good point. I will still keep it conversational, but then it is the same as the first option (Option 1) - the elements under each other

Comment: I think @JoaoCarvalho has a point. Smaller ≠ faster to process. Sometimes you can't even say how many fields are there from a quick look, as in example.

Comment: @Runnick I totally agree on that. Smaller ≠ faster to process.This is the reason why I say "It appears to be" = It is not, but it seems that it is